# How to access sub element of dictionary depending on another element?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Hey so I created this dictionary and want to be able access one of the elements based on another element. So within the main dictionary, I have a dictionary that holds "name" and "days" and based on a user input (they will input the day) and I want to output the name.

```
{1: {"name": "Leo", "days": range(1, 61)}, 2: {"name": "Gemini", "days": range(61, 122)}, ....
```

so with this example above, if the user inputs 25, I want to output "Leo". How can I do this? Initially I thought of doing just if statements, but is there a way to access the "name" sub-element based on the "days" sub-element?

so if the input is `25`, 
I want the output to be `Leo`

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is simple for-loop. Iterate over keys, check whether number is in 'days' range, if so print 'name' (or do whatever is needed with the name) and break (no need to iterate further). If no-break then print message about it (or take any other action).

```
for key in d:
    if 25 in d[key]['days']:
         print(d[key]['name'])
         break
else:
    print('Not found')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can scan through the elements in the dict

```
dict.items()
```

for example, using a list comprehension:

```
zodiac_signs = {1: {"name": "Leo", "days": range(1, 61)}, 2: {"name": "Gemini", "days": range(61, 122)}}
zodiac_matching_day = [zodiac['name'] \
                       for n, zodiac in zodiac_signs.items() \
                       if 25 in zodiac['days']]
if len(zodiac_matching_day) > 0:
    print(zodiac_matching_day[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way :

I've named your dict D and limited it to 2 elements.

```
D = {1: {"name": "Leo", "days": range(1, 61)}, 2: {"name": "Gemini", "days": range(61, 122)}}
```

We can define a lambda function to suit your need:

```
from_user = lambda x: [D[d] for d in D if x in D[d]['days']][0]['name']
```

`[D[d] for d in D]` allows to iterate over all the (name, days) elements.

`if x in D[d]['days']`is the condition one element has to honor and I suppose it's the case of only one.

I take the first one with `[0]` and then the `name`

`from_user(25)` returns `'Leo'`

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you want to structure your dictionary to make it easy to look up values based on the keys, so you might be better off redoing your dictionary so that the day number is the key, and the name is the value.

For example:

```
dict = {}
for num in range(1,12):
    if num > 6:
        dict[num] = 'Gemini'
    else:
        dict[num] = 'Leo'
dict

{1: 'Leo',
 2: 'Leo',
 3: 'Leo',
 4: 'Leo',
 5: 'Leo',
 6: 'Leo',
 7: 'Gemini',
 8: 'Gemini',
 9: 'Gemini',
 10: 'Gemini',
 11: 'Gemini'}
```

Then all you have to do is call dict[1], dict[7], and so forth.